# Large document txt to pdf

Tags: file-size

I have about 2 million lines of LaTeX code in a `.txt` file, and my computer cannot copy and paste it into ShareLatex so that I could compile it. Is there a better way I could get the LaTeX document from this?

IF the PDF size would be too large, what would be a better way to display this 2 million line LaTeX document?

Comment: Did you know that you could upload a file as well?

Comment: Have you tried copying the file and renaming it `.tex` and the compiling it?

Comment: @MarioS.E. I suspect OP does not have a local installation for whatever reason.  Two million lines is more than a reason to install one though---look into TeX Live / MikTeX and install LaTeX on your computer. Don't make ShareLaTeX compile 2m lines :)

Answer (score 2):

As Werner mentions you can upload files to ShareLaTeX. In an existing project, it is button number three from the left in the top left corner:

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a new project, and  select *Upload project*:

[image]

This requires a `.zip` file, so you have to compress your large file before uploading.